# Can a single thing be "mixed"?

Tags: word-usage

> Pastry is a food made from flour, fat, and water that is mixed together, rolled flat, and baked in the oven. It is used, for example, for making pies.

Source: 
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/pastry

Is the antecedent of this relative clause, "that is mixed together...", "a food"?

But I kind of feel it is illogical: how can a single thing be "mixed"?

Comment: But that isn’t what the sentence says. It lists the multiple ingredients that are mixed to make a single product. It is not the pastry that is mixed.

Comment: I would suggest an error in the quote too. “...that ARE mixed...” not “...that IS mixed...”. (Your link doesn’t work either)

Comment: @ Orbital Aussie Thanks for your suggestion. And I have fixed the link.

Comment: The live link does not dissuade me from my suggestion that the sentence is grammatically incorrect. Breaking it into the components, it says: 1) Pastry is a food. 2) It is made from [list of ingredients] that ARE mixed together...

Comment: Compare with these sentences:  “Ice is made from water that IS frozen.”  “Brine is made from salt and water that ARE mixed together.”

Comment: I got it，thanks.